# auto adjusting the positions and height width of UILabel in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have designed my help page for my application,it contains some FAQs..so I have used UILabels for question and answer,I have adjusted,x,y,width and height exactly in the xib,leaving a gap between a question and answer and answer and next question.so totally I have some 10 question and answers,I have put them inside a scroll view.

But now, suppose the text changes dynamically, how can I adjust the positions and width and height,is a problem which I am not able to figure out, by using the below code,it adjusts the height and width of a particular label,if the text increases

```
NSString * test=@" It may come as a rude shock, but Facebook users should not feel surprised if tomorrow they come across their photos existing in the web world despite having deleted them personally long ago.";
    m_testLabel.text = test;
   m_testLabel.numberOfLines = 0; //will wrap text in new line
    [m_testLabel sizeToFit];
```

but then, my next label will clash with it..is their any way so that all the labels get adjusted according if the width of any label increases or decreases?

Hope you all have understood my question..

Comment: I hope, for this, you do not need to anything programmatically.

Comment: Aadhira, thanks for ypour reply..will you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into the below function, pass the font you have used and the size to which u want to constraint the label into.

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
```

Comment: hey i got your point, this function,will adjust the parameters of one label,but what about the label below and above it..how to adjust their  positions, if suppose in one label ,text increases and decreases dynamically ,but the text in other labels dont change,then those labels will clash right..